# Consuming nuget package made with .nuspec and .targets (C++)

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, nuget, nuspec

Struggling to get a compiled c++ dll (both x86 and x64) packaged up so that a C# library can consume it.

Managed to pack and push the dll using nuspec file however when using VS2019 package manager it successfully installs the package however the reference does not appear. (Any Cpu)

.nuspec

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
    <metadata>
        <id>component1</id>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <description>mycomponent</description>
        <authors>Me</authors>
    </metadata> 
    <files>
        <file src="32\component1.dll"   target="build\x86" />
        <file src="64\component1.dll"   target="build\x64" />
        <file src="component1.targets"   target="lib\net40" />
    </files>
</package>
```

As the consuming project is targeting .NET 4.0 I created a component1.targets file pointing to the same framework

.targets

```
<ItemGroup Condition=" '$(Platform)' == 'x64' ">
    <Reference Include="component1">
              <HintPath>"$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\..\build\x64\component1.dll"</HintPath>
    </Reference>
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup Condition=" '$(Platform)' == 'x86' OR '$(Platform)' == 'AnyCPU' OR '$(Platform)' == 'Any CPU' ">
    <Reference Include="component1">
              <HintPath>$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\..\build\x32\component1.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: `$(Platform)' == 'AnyCPU'` declared twice, also you have `target="build\x86"` in package files, but `\build\x32` in `ItemGroup`

Comment: You may also need an itemgroup in your csproj file to copy the native dll to the output directory.

Comment: Hi gumby, any update about this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your steps are in a mess.

You should note that the targets file should be named as <package_id>.targets`, the same name as the nuget package id or it could not work. See [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package#include-msbuild-props-and-targets-in-a-package).

**Also**, the targets file should be put into `build` folder of **nupkg**.

That are the two importance tips.

**1)** Please change your `nuspec` file to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
    <metadata>
        <id>component1</id>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <description>mycomponent</description>
        <authors>Me</authors>
    </metadata> 
    <files>
        <file src="32\component1.dll"   target="build\x86" />
        <file src="64\component1.dll"   target="build\x64" />
        <file src="component1.targets"   target="build" />
    </files>
</package>
```

**2) Then**, change your `component1.targets` to these:

You should remove the `""` under `"$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\..\build\x64\component1.dll"`.

```
<Project>

<ItemGroup Condition=" '$(Platform)' == 'x64' ">
    <Reference Include="component1">
              <HintPath>$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\build\x64\component1.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup Condition=" '$(Platform)' == 'x86' OR '$(Platform)' == 'AnyCPU' OR '$(Platform)' == 'Any CPU' ">
    <Reference Include="component1">
              <HintPath>$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\build\x32\component1.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
</ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

**3)**  use `nuget pack` to repack the nuget package. And before you install this new version of the nuget package, please [clean nuget caches first](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders#clearing-local-folders) or just delete all files under `C:\Users\xxx(current user name)\.nuget\packages`.

And it works well in my side.

My nuget package is called `testt`, and I referenced `ClassLibrary21.dll` under `x64`.

[image]

Comment: That worked but I thought I would have to target the framework version. I'm guessing by putting .targets file in the build folder it will pick it up irrespective of the consuming framework.  Many thanks for your detailed answer